# android studio do not wrap xml

Tags: xml, android-studio

We have read more post than we care to admit so sorry for this question
We we are not getting results for our setting changes for Do Not Fold
We are using Android Studio 3.2.1
We have changed the Default settings and applications to Do Not Wrap for Value Layout and Other XML

The top XML file is what we want the one below it is what we are getting

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_id"
        android:text="TextView 1 "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
<TextView
        android:text="TextView 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_id" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
```

We even close out of Android Studio after the changes
Is this a Kotlin Issue we say NOT because we are talking XML only

So we give up. The question is what are we doing wrong?